# Plotly dash app.long_callback arguments with states

Tags: python, plotly-dash

```
@app.long_callback(
    outputs = Output("optimize-result", "children"),
    inputs = Input("optimize-button-id", "n_clicks"),
    states = dict(
        reorder_period = State("reorder-period-dropdown-id", "value"),
        forecast = State("forecast-dropdown-id", "value")
    ),
    running = [
        (Output("optimize-button-id", "disabled"), True, False),
    ],
    prevent_initial_call = True,
)
def load_optimize_data_button_click(number_clicks, reorder_period, forecast):
```

How can this be fixed. It leads to a `TypeError: load_optimize_data_button_click() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'reorder_period' and 'forecast'`

With a normal callback this works, see this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("optimize-result", "children"),
    Input("optimize-button-id", "n_clicks"),
    State("reorder-period-dropdown-id", "value"),
    State("forecast-dropdown-id", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call = True,
)
def load_optimize_data_button_click(number_clicks, reorder_period, forecast):
```

I have troubles, because I cannot find an api documentation of the arguments that app.long_callback takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
@app.long_callback(
    output=Output("optimize-result", "children"),
    inputs=dict(number_clicks=Input("optimize-button-id", "n_clicks")),
    state=dict(
        reorder_period=State("reorder-period-dropdown-id", "value"),
        forecast=State("forecast-dropdown-id", "value")
    ),
    running=[
        (Output("optimize-button-id", "disabled"), True, False),
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def load_optimize_data_button_click(number_clicks, reorder_period, forecast):
    pass
```

Firstly, according to the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/flexible-callback-signatures), use `state` instead of `states`. Secondly, the data type of both inputs and state apparently needs to be same, either both of them as list or both dict.

The above code worked with Dash 2.0.0. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.long_callback(
    Output("optimize-result", "children"),
    Input("optimize-button-id", "n_clicks"),
    [State("reorder-period-dropdown-id", "value"),
     State("forecast-dropdown-id", "value")],
    running=[
        (Output("optimize-button-id", "disabled"), True, False),
    ],
    prevent_initial_call = True,
)
```